# Git/GitHub pull request filtering

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

The setup:

- A repository owned by someone else on GitHub that I forked to work on
  making changes
- I use GitHub on my Windows machine to pull down that fork to my
  system, where I make my edits and at the end of the day, I commit and
  sync my changes back up to my fork.
- Every few days, I will also (re)sync with the (upstream) repository so I
  keep up to date with changes being made there as well. I do this
  through command line actions in Git (for desktop), pulling down upstream, then merging it with my own locally, before syncing it back up to my own fork.

Now comes the fun part. I also work on the code when I'm at the office. So I have a similar setup, where I use GitHub at work and pull down my fork, work on the files, and I commit and sync before I come home in the evening. When I get home, I will pull down whatever changes I made so my local copy is synced with the changes I made throughout the day.

The issue I'm having is when I want to do a pull request with the master branch. It will pull in every little detail of what I've been doing locally, including the constant sync and merging of the main repository. An example can be seen here:

[image: pull request example]

There's also a list of items for which it's telling me the filemode has changed. So, is there a way to do a pull request where it's ignoring those merges with the upstream (master) repository? All of the commits are my own commits to my fork. When I do a pull request, all I want to do is do it against the final file and the upstream master. They don't need to see all of my little updates that I did throughout the day.

Or, should I be doing this differently?

Comment: You could squash the commits, but that would be rewriting history.  Better yet, you could squash the commits locally _before_ pushing to GitHub.

Comment: However, squashing _before_ committing to GitHub wouldn't work as I have to commit to GitHub when I leave the office, so I can grab those changes when I get home, and same when I'm done at home, I have to commit back to GitHub so I can grab those changes at work again the next day.

Comment: No, I disagree.  The "truth" about your branch is whatever actually sits on GitHub.  If a squash commit is there, then this is what you pull when you get home.

Comment: So that I understand what you're suggesting: during the day, at work, I work on files, and I commit changes (on GitHub for Windows), like before I go to lunch or a break. I end up with several commits that way. At the end of the day, I hit '**sync**' so all those commits go up to GitHub. You're suggesting here, before I sync, to squash all those commits into one, and then sync? Yes?

Then when I get home, resync the now outdated copy I have at home with what GitHub has. I continue working, make commits, and at the end of the night, squash them all prior to hitting 'sync' again. Yes?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking :-)

Comment: Aha, ok that's starting to make more sense now. I think, for me to "fix" the current situation, it would probably be better for me to start fresh, as in, stash the changes I've made so far, get rid of the fork with the millions of commits. Refork the main project again, add my changes back to it, with commit squashing prior to syncing, and then create a PR. That ought to provide a clean(er) PR for the project owner, one that doesn't have dozens of itty bitty commits listed.

Comment: This sounds like a plan.  I feel that in general you should not need to squash your commits, if those commits each represent a logical piece of functionality in your code.  But if you have thousands of them then maybe squashing makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to do a pull request with the master branch.

GitHub recently added "[Squash your commits](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)": that would allow to get your PR all squashed:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/143418/14119749/7756ff60-f5a4-11e5-8597-12dcbb363746.png]

Comment: When I create a pull request (from my fork to the upstream repository), all I get is a button that reads 'create pull request'. What you're showing me here is unknown to me unfortunately.

Comment: @KirAsh4 as described in https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits, you need to activate that mode.

Comment: Right, in *my* (forked) repository, those options are enabled. I have no clue if the same is true for the upstream repository, that's not mine.